# (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) PHP 5.4 offline install

Tags: 12.04, installation, php, offline

I searched but didnt find solution to our problem...

We have offline (intranet) Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installation. We made local offline Ubuntu 12.04 repo mirror (updating once in a week) and I can install all other things from there.
But how to install PHP 5.4? Repo mirror contains only PHP 5.3.x version.
I've read that there is somekind "ondrej/...." PPA where is PHP 5.4 for 12.04 LTS but I cant access to this location from my offline network Ubuntu.
How to create local mirror or download all required packages from this PPA? Is there procedure for this like apt-mirror script for mirroring repository?

Thank U all,

//Progeja.

Comment: Do you have access to any other computer with Ubuntu that is connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download latest version of PHP from:
[Official PHP download page](http://php.net/downloads.php)

And extract the file usually in tar format, see the **INSTALL** file and follow the step by step instructions for installation of PHP.